# Event Listener not being added

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, addeventlistener

So I have a problem with an Event listener not being added on the id closeBtn when it's inserted through JavaScript via an if statement to check the localStorage for the user type. I check the userType because I have different navs for different userTypes.

When I don't load in the html code of the nav via JavaScript and just have it in the html-doc the closeBtn works but for some reason it doesn't when inserted via JavaScript. The weird part is that the id navBtn does work which also gets an Event Listener at the same place as the closeBtn.

```js
let nav = {
  navBtn: document.getElementById('navBtn'),
  closeBtn: document.getElementById('closeBtn'),
  overlay: document.getElementById('overlay'),
  nav: document.getElementById('nav'),
  initnav: function() {
    if (this.nav) {
      if (localStorage.getItem('userType')) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('userType') == "company") {
          // prettier-ignore
          this.nav.innerHTML = `
                <main>
                    <aside>
                        <img src="./media/images/Erasmushogeschool-logo.png" alt="Erasmushogeschool Brussel logo">
                    </aside>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="./indexbedrijven.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./careerlaunch2022.html">Careerlaunch 2022</a></li>
                        <li><a href="vacatures_bedrijven.html">Vacatures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./agenda.html">Mijn Agenda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./chats_bedrijf.html">Chat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./index.html">Careerlaunch voor studenten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </main>
                <footer>
                <div div class = "accountBtns" >
                    <div class="account" >
                    <a href = "./account.html" >
                        <div class="profilePic myProfile"></div>
                        <h4 id="userName">Vince</h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <button>Afmelden</button>
                </div>
                <div id="closeBtn">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
                </footer>
                `;
        } else if (localStorage.getItem('userType') == "student") {
          // prettier-ignore
          this.nav.innerHTML = `
                <main>
                    <aside>
                        <img src="./media/images/Erasmushogeschool-logo.png" alt="Erasmushogeschool Brussel logo">
                    </aside>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./careerlaunch2022.html">Careerlaunch 2022</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./planning.html">Planning</a></li>
                        <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="favorieten.html">Favoriete vacatures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./agenda.html">Mijn Agenda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="chats.html">Chat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="game.html">Careerlaunch game</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </main>
                <footer>
                    <a class="account" href="./account.html">
                        <div>
                            <div class="profilePic myProfile"></div>
                            <h4 id="userName">Vince</h4>
                        </div>
                        <button>Afmelden</button>
                    </a>
                    <div id="closeBtn">
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                </footer>
                `;
        }
      } else {
        //prettier-ignore
        this.nav.innerHTML = `
            <main>
            <aside>
                <img src="./media/images/Erasmushogeschool-logo.png" alt="Erasmushogeschool Brussel logo">
            </aside>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Careerlaunch 2022</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
                <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
                <li><a href="favorieten.html">Favoriete vacatures</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Mijn Agenda</a></li>
                <li><a href="chats.html">Chat</a></li>
                <li><a href="game.html">Careerlaunch game</a></li>
            </ul>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <div class="notLogged">
                    <div>
                        <a href="registreren_1-4.html" class="bluebox">Registreren</a>
                        <a href="login_student.html" class="graybox">log in</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="closeBtn">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </footer>
            `;
      }
      this.navEventListnr();
    }

  },
  navEventListnr: function() {
    this.navBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      nav.animateNav("open");
    });
    console.log("closeListner");
    this.closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      nav.animateNav("close");
    });
  },
  animateNav: function(action) {
    console.log('open');
    if (action == "open") {
      this.navBtn.style.display = "none";
      this.overlay.style.display = "block";
      this.overlay.style.opacity = ".7";
      this.nav.style.right = "0vw";
    } else if (action == "close") {
      console.log('close');
      this.navBtn.style.display = "flex";
      this.nav.style.right = "-80vw";
      this.overlay.style.opacity = "0";
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.overlay.style.display = "none";
      }, 100);
    }
  }
};

nav.initnav();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Careerlaunch</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/index.css">
  <script type="module" src="./js/index.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color: green;">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="navBtn">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <nav id='nav'>
    <main>
      <aside>
        <img src="./media/images/Erasmushogeschool-logo.png" alt="Erasmushogeschool Brussel logo">
      </aside>
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Careerlaunch 2022</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Planning</a></li>
        <li><a href="vacatures.html">Vacatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="favorieten.html">Favoriete vacatures</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Mijn Agenda</a></li>
        <li><a href="chats.html">Chat</a></li>
        <li><a href="game.html">Careerlaunch game</a></li>
      </ul>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="notLogged">
        <div>
          <a href="registreren_1-4.html" class="bluebox">Registreren</a>
          <a href="login_student.html" class="graybox">log in</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="closeBtn">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Because `closeBtn: document.getElementById('closeBtn'),` is run BEFORE you add a close button to the document! How is it supposed to find the element that you set with innerHTML? You are going to have to set closeBtn after you add the element to the page or use event delegation.

Comment: Instead of adding HTML dynamically, I recommend you put it in the original HTML. Then use JavaScript to hide and show relevant parts of it based on local storage.

Comment: Agree with @Barmar. Decouple this HTML entirely from JavaScript rendering. The HTML isn't inside of the document object yet so you can't latch onto any element and assign an event listener. This wouldn't be the case if the markup was already standalone and already rendered. In that case, the document method getElementById() would then be able to access it.

Comment: Also, the `<script>` tag that loads the JS needs to be at the end of the HTML, or it needs to call `nav.initnav()` from the `load` event listener.